# Import multiple files with a glob

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I am building a modular react app. But I am running into an issue where I can't dynamically import the routes of my app. Imagine this:

`app
├── app.js
└── modules
    ├── module_1
    │   └── routes.js
    ├── module_2
    │   └── routes.js
    └── module_3
        └── routes.js`

Imagine all the routes.js files containing something like this:

```
//modules/module_*/route.js
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

export default () => {
    <Route path="/module/path" component={ModuleComponent}>
};
```

I would then in my app.js to be able to do this:

```
const Routes = import('modules/**/routes.js');

const App = () => (
   <BrowserRouter>
       <Routes />
   </BrowserRouter>
);
export default App;
```

Right now im running a separate node script that creates an index file for al the routes.js files but this is getting tedious. And i am hoping there might be a better way to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The npm package `import-glob` does exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

--edit---

The package basically does what @E. Sundin described in his post. You basically add the package as a pre-loader in your JavaScript files which allows you to do

```
import modules from "./foo/**/*.js";
```

And the package expands it into:

```
import * as module0 from "./foo/1.js";
import * as module1 from "./foo/bar/2.js";
import * as module2 from "./foo/bar/3.js";

modules = [module0, module1, module2]
```

Comment: See https://www.npmjs.com/package/import-glob 
but in current (2021) WebPack, `preloaders[n].loader` must be written as an entry in `rules[n].use` e.g. 
`use: [ 'eslint-loader', 'import-glob']` 
which makes `import-glob` run *before* `eslint-loader`.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `index.js` in each folder you want to export things from and in the structure you want.

You could for instance `export * from './routes'` in each of your modules and then in turn export these in your `modules` folder like

```
import route1 from './module_1';
import route2 from './module_2';
import route3 from './module_3';
export const routes = [route1, route2, route3];
```

Then in your `app.js` you `import { routes } from './modules` and apply these similiar to:

```
{routes.map((route, i) => <Routes key="{i}"/>)}
```

Comment: The problem it's a modular application. I will have to update the Router everytime a module gets added or deleted. The example you have given is already how I do it now, but I run a filewatcher instead to do the indexing for me. I was hoping for a more elegant solution tho.