# Different export type in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible in JavaScript to do something like: `export * from '*/**'`?

Expect to export all modules from the entry point (`index.js`) like:

```
export * from '*/**.js'
```

Instead of:

```
export * from './thing.js'
export * from './something/something.js`
```

Comment: Native JS does not support `glob` pattern imports. Maybe this question can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53216259/import-multiple-files-with-a-glob

Answer (score 0):

```
export const doSomething = () => {}
export const doSomethingElse = () => {}
```

or in an index.js file like

```
export * from './bar';
```

It's done like above and then you use the functions in bar like this:

```
import * as foo from '../foo/bar';

foo.doSomething();
```

If you only want doSomething() then this should work:

```
import { doSomething } from '../foo/bar';
```

Comment: No that's not what I'm looking for.
inside the entry point, I want to export every module with `export * from '**/*`